# How to create a wrapper function in stylus?

Tags: stylus

I want to create a function that wraps another built-in function in stylus. Something like:

```
myFunction(color, amount)
    darken(color, amount)
```

I want to create multiple themes for a project, and in that some themes are dark and some are light, so for `hover` I want to `lighen()` the `background-color` and for the others `darken()`, and use `myFunction()` in a file that is common among all the themes, only changes the function definition in each theme.

**What I want to know:** Is it possible at all? Or if there is any other mechanism for function polymorphism in stylus, any method to be able to change the definition of function dynamically.

**What I have tried:**

- First I tried to wrap simply like:

  ```
  inHover (color, amount)
      darken(color, amount)
  ```

  But I got:

  ```
  cmd.exe /D /C E:/node/nodist/bin/stylus.cmd definitions.styl
  E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\bin\stylus:662
                throw err;
                ^

  RangeError: definitions.styl:20:10
     16| 
     17| /* Functions */
     18| 
     19| inHover (color, amount)
     20|   darken(color, amount)
  ----------------^
     21| 

  Maximum call stack size exceeded
      at darken() (E:/node/nodist/bin/node_modules/stylus/lib/functions/index.styl:128:21)
      at "inHover (color" (definitions.styl:18:16)

      at Evaluator.visit (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:162:34)
      at Evaluator.visitIdent (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:533:23)
      at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\index.js:28:40)
      at Evaluator.visit (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:156:18)
      at Evaluator.visitExpression (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:630:26)
      at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\index.js:28:40)
      at Evaluator.visit (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:156:18)
      at Evaluator.visitIdent (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:533:23)
      at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\index.js:28:40)
      at Evaluator.visit (E:\node\nodist\bin\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\evaluator.js:156:18)
  ```
- I cannot use blocks, since they do not accept arguments.

**My code:**

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='/css/themes/my_theme/index.css' rel='styleSheet'/>
    <body ng-app='app'>

        <!-- Body defination -->

    </body>
</html>
```

`/css/themes/my_theme/index.styl` file:

```
@import 'definitions.styl'

@import '../../site.styl' /* All the common css styles*/

myFunction(color, amount)
    darken(color, amount)
```

`/css/themes/my_theme/definitions.styl` file:

```
/* Color definitions */
colorPrimary = red
colorBackground = green

/* Functions */
inHover (color, amount)
  darken(color, amount)
```

**What I use:**

- stylus 0.52.4
- Node 4.1.1
- express 4.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this code works for me (try to remove the space before `(` in the function definition):

```
inHover(color, amount)
  darken(color, amount)

body
  color: inHover(#c00, 10)
```

Compiles with Stylus 0.52.4 to:

```
body {
  color: #900;
}
```

Comment: Even I just tried it in isolation, and it was working, this seems the problem is somewhere else.